# How can i go on from here? Trying to build a weather featcher

Tags: python, api, weather

```
import requests

API_KEY = '...'
API_LINK = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
city = input('enter your city: ')
request_url = f"{API_LINK}?appid={API_KEY}&q={city}"
```

I'm trying to build a weather fetcher, don't wanna see the code but I'm so lost at the moment. Can you guys help? Don't write the code, just tell me what to do.

and also on the 4th line of the code, i'm not supposed to know these (appid, &q) right? Are they in the module?

Comment: you have to fill in your API_KEY in the api_key string -- there is no module that will give you those values, after you have the request_url filled you should likely use the `requests` module to `get` the information from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the API you're using, but you can probably get the response by doing something like this

```
import requests

# make session
session = requests.Session()

# call API
resp = session.get(’your url’)

# print response
print(resp.text)
```